# Preview testnet transactions

Tags: testnet

I want to access an address that is on preview testnet and create transactions to spend all tADA. How can I do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way: https://namiwallet.io

1. Install browser-extension wallet, such as Nami
2. Restore your wallet with the mnemonics and the passphrase
3. Set Nami to use preview testnet (default is mainnet)
4. transfer tADA to the address you so choose

The hard way: cardano-cli

1. Install/run cardano-node by: https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/installing-cardano-node
2. Restore wallet and create transaction by cardano-cli like: https://developers.cardano.org/docs/integrate-cardano/creating-wallet-faucet

The not-so-hard way: https://blockfrost.dev

Answer (score 1):

You first need to generate keys to derive an address from. Addresses that are already in use are not accessible unless you hold the associated signing key.

One way to get started is with the cardano-cli. See https://docs.cardano.org/cardano-testnet/getting-started